# Which book do you recommend to start studying physics for a person who doesn't have any special knowledge about physics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations

I'm studying bachelor of Mathematics in University but I'm interested in physics too. All of my knowledge about physics is what I studied in school and also the courses general physics $I$ and general physics $II$ in university.

I want to know what is your recommendation for a start point of studying physics? And also what books do you suggest me?

Comment: Which of the tens of thousands of books on mathematics from the mathematics library would you advise a physicist to read? Why do you think that a physicist can give a better recommendation on physics books than a mathematician can give on mathematics books?

Comment: @CuriousOne  Of course I have some recommendation for a person who wants to start studying mathematics,  and surly a physicist can give me good recommendation for a start point!